# How to create a texture with mipmap auto-generated?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I think opengl can automatically generate mipmap texture, does XNA support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Select your image file in the Content project. In the Properties, expand the Content Processor, and set "Generate Mipmaps" to "True".